# How to fix "string indices must be integers, not 'str'", that I am getting while practicing with Pandas DataReader?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-datareader, exploratory-data-analysis

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import datetime as dt
df = pdr.DataReader('MSFT','yahoo', start='2021-4-15', end='2023-04-14')
df.head()
```

**O/P:**

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'.
```

I was trying to get the stock data as dataframe using pandas datareader library, while practicing and learning.

but in O/P it's throwing error as

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```

How to fix it ? I have gone through the pd datareader documentation, where they also shown the exact code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

pdr.get_data_yahoo('MSFT',start='2021-4-15',end='2023-4-14')
```

That is how you can access the data until the issue with package will be solved.

Comment: It's showing same error         
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Comment: Than import yfinance firstly. ```import yfinance as yf```. After that use override method ```yf.pdr_override()```